# how to customize the radio button in Django

Tags: html, css, django, forms, django-templates

template.py

```
{{ FormatForm.date_format }}
```

The above template is rendering the output in the following format in image [image: sample image]

I am using model form.

Is it possible to customize the radio button so that the bullet points at the left of each radio button is not required or how to remove the bullet point at the left of radio button.
I am using `django 1.3.7`,can any one tell me how to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Small change in Hedde's answer worked for me

```
ul li {
       list-style: none;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a css question and has little to do with django,

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

You could however add your own renderer to use a different html markup instead, see the widget documentation